# Binomial coefficient recursive function in C - brings wrong result, why?

Tags: c, debugging, recursion, binomial-coefficients

beginner here trying to understand the source of the bug.

I have written this recursive function for finding the binomial coefficient between two numbers which is apparently correct in concept. However, for these two numbers, n =4 and k=2, I should be getting 6 as a result whereas I actually get 16. Any idea why is that happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int binomial(int n, int k)
{
  if ((k = 0) || (k == n))
    return 1;
  if (k>n)
    return 0;

  return binomial(n - 1, k - 1) + binomial(n - 1, k);
}

int main()    
{
  int a, b, res;
  a = 4;
  b = 2;
  res = binomial(a, b);
  printf("The result is %d", res);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`

Comment: please consider accepting answers if they that helped you (it also gives you 2 rep points :) )

Answer (score 5):

This line looks wrong as it assigns 0 to `k`:

```
if ((k=0) || (k==n))
```

You probably mean:

```
if ((k==0) || (k==n))
```

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
 if ((k = 0) || (k == n))
```

should be

```
  if ((k == 0) || (k == n))  
         ^^
```

You were assigning zero to k.

As @Michael Walz points out, it's good practice to compile with  `-Wall` to turn on all compilation warnings.

Comment: Ohhhh, I see! Will pay more attention to syntax next time. Thanks!

Comment: I am not really familiar with -wall  though

Comment: add it to your compile command assuming you are using gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html